# Cronjob not working - trying to run PHP script

Tags: php, cron

I am running a cronjob that runs a PHP script to do a couple of things; first, it opens the database and stores the contents of the tables into memcache;  second it creates a Javascript file that is basically a couple of arrays so that the client browser can do a lot of the work and save the server from being overloaded. This is newly added.

The script runs manually very well, and for over a year it has done its job, updating memcache every 10 minutes. The Javascript file add on is the big problem here; the cronjob s/b creating a new, updated edition of this file every 10 minutes, but appears to be not working unless I run it manually from the command line.

I can check this by doing:

```
ls -al id_index.js
```

and checking the timestamp in the file listing.

Is there some problem with creating a Javascript file from a script started by crontab?

Btw, the cronjob file entry looks like this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/10 * * * * php /home/accountname/public_html/mc_store_arrays.php
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try specifying the whole path to `php`?

Comment: Try logging the output to a file (appending the cronjob with `>/path/to/some.log`) and check what gets put there.

Comment: try to run this "php /home/accountname/public_html/mc_store_arrays.php" from terminal and see what you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which directory are you expecting the javascript file to be created? It probably *is* being created somewhere ... wherever cron's working directory happens to be when the script runs (`/root/` perhaps?). Make sure your output file is specified with an absolute path or with e.g:

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/id_index.js', $content);
```

which will create the file based on the path of the php script that's running, rather than the path from which it was executed.

Comment: It turns out this was correct. It was creating the file where ever the crontab.xxxx directory was. I specified the absolute path to the directory and it worked as expected. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will have to specify the absolute path to the php cli interpreter, since the cron environment rarely defines a usable PATH environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

Try using LYNX (just the way you use a web browser);

Example: **LYNX** http://www.MyDomain.Com/MyScript.php?MyParameter=MyValue&And=SoOn

Comment: Misleading question title :(